# Class.forName doesn't work while trying to connect to MySQL database

Tags: java

I have a problem using mysql. It seems that when the program runs into this part, it doesn't continue [SOLVED]

```
        try{
        //Load the Driver Class
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

I think there is a problem in this part of code. because I tried this, the JOptionPane popped up:

```
        try{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ok!");
        //Load the Driver Class
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

but, when I wrote the code like this, nothing happens:

```
        try{
        //Load the Driver Class
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ok!");
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

BTW, this is my whole program

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String user = userName.getText();
    final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/videorental";

    if(user.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fields should not be empty", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else{
        try{
        //Load the Driver Class
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //Create the connection using the static getConnection method
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connecting to database");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "root", "");
        //Create statement to execute the SQL statement
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Creating a statement");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        //Check the username
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from 'user_tbl' where user_id = '"+user+"' ");
        if(rs.next()){
            String uname = rs.getString("user_id");
            if(user.equals(uname)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you!");
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You are not registered.");
            }
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }     


}
```

So I tried putting e.printStackTrace(), sorry I'm really a newbie in using mySQL. So here is the result... [SOLVED]

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at user.loginFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(loginFrame.java:113)
    at user.loginFrame.access$000(loginFrame.java:14)
    at user.loginFrame$1.actionPerformed(loginFrame.java:48)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

And I don't have any idea what these errors are. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

BTW, I'm using netbeans as an IDE.

Thanks guys for the help but a new problem arises, it says that I have MYSQLSYntaxError

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user_tbl' where user_id = '12345678'' at line 1
```

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {}` - **AAAARRRRGGGGHHH**. Don't swallow exceptions, otherwise you have no clue what's going on... like here.

Comment: Seriously, put `e.printStackTrace();` into the catch block and post the stacktrace too see what's the problem..

Comment: @KubaSpatny Or forgo the catch entirely .. I very rare have catch "print stuff". Handle it usefully or GTEO (get the exception out).

Comment: @user2864740 Yeah of course, I meant just for the sake of seeing what's the problem here..

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new here. I just took all your advices and edited my post. Can you help me again? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to add the `mysql.jar` to your project. Also as noted  the comment, don't swallow your exception. If you do this, you have no idea what the error or. It could be `ClassNotFoundException` or an `SQLException` which are completely different things. Once you add the `ex.printStackTrace()` to your `catch` block, if you get a `ClassNotFoundException`, you probably forgot to import he `mysql.jar` into you project. If you get an `SQLExcpetion`, something is either wrong with your SQL syntax or your connection syntax

---

**EDIT** to include jar

- Download the `.zip` from [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)
- Unzip it
- From your IDE, you need to add the `.jar` that's in that file, to your Libraries
- From Eclipse

  1. Right-click on you project
  2. Select - Buil Path => Configure Path
  3. Click on the tab Libraries, at the top
  4. Cick on Add External Jar
  5. locate the `mysqul-connector.java...jar` inside the file you downloaded and select it
- From Netbeans

  1. From your project in the project explorer, Right-click `Libraries` folder icon
  2. Select `Add Jar/Folder`
  3. Locate the `.jar` from the file you downloaded, and select it.
- If you want to create a new Library, there are other steps you should take, but just adding the `.jar` is sufficent.

---

**UPDATE**

I think the `MySQL.jar` comes shipped with the Netbeans IDE.

- Try to right-click on the `Libraries` folder icon
- Select Add library
- See if MySQL JDBC Driver is in there. If it is, just select it and Add Library

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just googled the errors I get and it seems that i need that JAR file. However I do not know what JAR files are and where to put them.

What part in my code will i put that mysql.jar. Thank you for the response

Comment: Are you using an IDE, and which one if you are?

Comment: Thanks. I have MySQL JDBC Driver. My problem for classFornmae not found. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? Also did you acutally `ADD the Library`. You still need to add it. The library exists in Netbeans, but you still need to add it to your project

Comment: Sorry typo error, I mean my problem about classForName is already solved. However a new problem arises, it says that I have a MySQLSyntaxError...
>
>
>
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user_tbl' where user_id = '12345678'' at line 1

Comment: Sorry but this site is not really a help desk. It's more a Q & A site. If your main problem is solved, please accept and answer (the check mark), then ask another question on the site (regarding your SQL syntax)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a piece of code of the form:

```
try {
    A();
    B();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

and `B` is not being executed, it's a pretty safe bet that `A` is raising an exception of some type, *especially* if `B` does what it's meant to if the order is reversed.

In your case:

```
catch (Exception e) {}
```

is catching the exception but doing absolutely nothing to fix or report it. At a *bare minimum,* you should report it with something like `System.out.println (e);` or `e.printStackTrace()` so you can see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should add MySQL.jar which comes with Netbeans IDE.

1. There is a Libraries folder inside the project you create.
2. Right click the folder and click on Add Library.
3. From available Libraries, click on MySQL JDBC Driver (if using MySQL).